# How to power 12v DC pneumatic solenoid?

Tags: batteries, solenoid

i am having a 12v dc pneumatic solenoid. It's mentioned with 200mA. Can i use 12 V 1.3 AH battery to power it up?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Your battery should last \$ \frac {1.3\ \mathrm{Ah}}{0.2 \ \mathrm A} = 6.5\ \mathrm h \$ from full charge.

Comment: Is it means my battery is suit for the solenoid?

Comment: I don't know. You didn't tell us how many hours you need.